# OpenSSL Fips in C++ Wrapper Library How To? Err: fingerprint does not match

Tags: c++, c, windows, openssl, fips

I am attempting to compile a static wrapper dll that includes the static OpenSSL Fips libraries.

I have linked:

```
C:\Work\win_x64\fipscanister.lib
C:\Work\libeayfips32.lib
C:\Work\ssleay32.lib
ws2_32.lib
crypt32.lib
```

I also included the directory of the libs in the includes directory.

I have added the fips_premain.c file that was generated during the openssl-fip2.0 build. I adjusted the SHA1_HASH_SIG to equal the value in fips_premain.c.sha1

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to build my wrapper dll. I include the wrapper dll in my project. When I call, FIPS_mode_set(1), I get the following errors:

```
17480:error:2D0A3073:FIPS routines:func(163):fips selftest failed:
.\crypto\ecdh\ech_ossl.c:125: Exception thrown:
'System.Exception' in Test.OpenSSL.dll [Test][11872][26]
ERROR [Native][-] 2018-10-03T01:13:54.971Z ERROR 
Setting fips mode: fingerprint does not match
[Native][11872][27] ERROR [Native][-] 2018-10-03T01:13:54.972Z 
ERROR Setting fips mode: fingerprint does not match Exception thrown: 'System.Exception'
in Test.OpenSSL.dll Exception thrown:
'System.NullReferenceException' in Test.OpenSSL.dll
```

When I ran **nmake ­f ms\nt.mak test** all the tests completed successfully

I must be missing a step somewhere, I am curious how others have gotten this to work.

I built the library like:

```
perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-64 
ms\do_win64a 
nmake -f ms\nt.mak  
nmake -f ms\nt.mak install
```

Im using openssl-1.0.2p and openssl-fips-2.0.16 Both built properly which makes me think its how I am building my wrapper. Or maybe its unable to process the hash because its been wrapped?

Comment: Did you look at (*OpenSSL*) build log? Does it mention *fips*? As a test, what happens if you remove *fipscanister.lib* from *VStudio* in your project? Does it build? You seem to have misconfigured it (*OpenSSL*). `perl Configure VC-WIN64A --prefix=C:\Build-OpenSSL-VC-64`: you must also pass `fips ­­--with­fipsdir=%FIPS_INSTALL_DIR%` (where *%FIPS\_INSTALL\_DIR%* is the directory where *fips* is installed (*do\_fips*)) arguments. Is it reproducible if you build *OpenSSL* dynamic? Check https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

So I had to add the fips_premain.c to my visual studio project. Run fips_premain_dso.exe passing in my new static lib (make sure the fips_premain.c isnt changed or it wont generate the hash) and then put the hash value into the fips_premain.c and then rebuild in visual studio and it works :D